# Iterate JSON Data by some time limit in react native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Currently i have a `<Text>` values inside a `<View>` in **react-native** . and i have to pass one JSON to iterate over that text field . so how i want them to be is  , Assume the JSON contains 4 objects , So initially The text field will show the first object's value inside the `<View>` . After 5 seconds instead of first object i have to show the Second object . like wise it has to goes  on until the last object come's . For example ,

```js
 const mydata = [
 {
  name:"Aaa"  //object 1
 },
 {
  name:"Bbb"  //object 2
 },
 {
   name:"Ccc" //object 3
 },
 {
   name:"Ddd"  //object 5
 },
 
 ]
 
 
 //initial view
 <View>
 <Text>{object1.name} </Text>   /// ---> Aaa
 </View>
 
 //After 5 seconds
  <View>
 <Text>{object2.name} </Text>   /// ---> Bbb
 </View>
 
 //Like this it has to go on .
```

and it need's to be change automatically for every 5 seconds .Here i attached my code ,

```js
<View>
          {allData.map((data,i) => (
          <DataInDetail      // this is the component i imported
          name={data.name}
          />
     ))}
     
 </View>
 
 
 //DataInDetail component
 
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";


const win = Dimensions.get("window");
const width = win.width;

export default class DataInDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <View>
         <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>  
         </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now it is showing the last JSON only . pls someone clarify me from this . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to achive this. Check [TimerMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html#timermixin) to use `this.setTimeout`. TimerMixin helps you with the state setting error after the components unmount.

**Example**

```
const data = [ { name:"Aaa" }, { name:"Bbb" }, { name:"Ccc" }, { name:"Ddd" } ];
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    data.forEach((d, index) => {
      this.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setSTate({ name: d.name });
      }, (5000 * index))
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <DataInDetail name={this.state.name} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** (To make it loop indefinitely)
You can turn the `setTimeout` loop into a function and can call it at the last index of the loop. We increment `index` by one because we want change happen after 5 seconds after the initial start.

```
const data = [ { name:"Aaa" }, { name:"Bbb" }, { name:"Ccc" }, { name:"Ddd" } ];
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
  }

  setLoop(isIntial) {
    data.forEach((d, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setSTate({ name: d.name }, () => {
          if (index == (data.length - 1)) this.setLoop.bind(this, false);
        });
      }, (isInitial === true ? (5000 * index) : (5000 * (index + 1) )));
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setLoop(true);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <DataInDetail name={this.state.name} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me implement this now and update you here buddy :)

Comment: I got one error while implementing ur code , error : Undefined is not a function,(evaluating` '_this2.setTimeout(() => {
        this2.setState({ name: d.name });
      }, (5000 * index)')` .

Comment: Did you check the TimerMixin page I told you about? You need to install it before using. If you don't want to install just use `setTimeout` rather than `this.setTimeout`

Comment: Hey thanks man , Your code worked for me :) I just changed one thing  instead of *this.setTimeout* i just gave *setTimeout * .

Comment: One more doubt i have :  How to repeat that loop ? For example : now the iteration goes from 0 to 4 and then stops . My question here is  , is there any way to repeat that loop ? Like 0 to 4 then again 0 to 4  . .like that ?

Comment: this.setLoop.bind(this, true);  --> this line didnt works for me !!! i put console.log on that method  .. but i didnt printed !!

Comment: try just running `this.setLoop(true)`

Comment: Hey bro , do  you Know how to solve "Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op."   this error ?

Comment: Its the thing I told you about at the first place. Please read carefully. Check the documentation I gave in the answer.